# Should tag-only edits result in disputing a flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

If you flag a question as very low quality, an edit to the question results in the flag entering the "disputed" state. The rationale behind this is quite clear: you marked the question non-salvageable, yet someone tried to salvage it.

Should the same logic apply to tag-only edits? More precisely, should re-tagging a question count as an attempt to salvage it?

Here is the [question that I have in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418554/what-do-you-mean-by-a-baked-website); it had been closed for three hours at the time the tag-only edit has been applied.

Comment: Why would someone flag that as very low quality? It should be deleted because it's off-topic, but it's certainly not a low quality question, per say.

Comment: Hmm, I could have sworn that I also submitted a delete vote when I nuked those new tags.  Tag edits totally shouldn't dispute or clear moderator flags, IMO...